# Form POST requests are empty / undefined using NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm setting up routes in an API and even simple forms do not seem to send any data at all.  Here's a simple form html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="/comments" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="John"><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="Doe"><br>
    <label for="comments">Comments:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="comments" name="comments" value="Some comments"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the app.js running in Node:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan')

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = express();
const router = express.Router();

server.use(express.static(__dirname));

server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(morgan('dev'));

server.post('/comments', (req, res) => {
  console.log('reached this API call');
  console.log('sending back to homepage');
  console.log('you sent: ' + req.body);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));

});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

This is what I see in the console after I click the Submit button:

Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/
reached this API call
sending back to homepage
you sent: [object Object]
POST /comments 200 2.944 ms - 20059

the [object Object] has no data in it.  I've tried accessing req.body.name and it is undefined.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For parsing of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post data, you need to add

```js
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

For properly logging the full `req.body`

```js
const util = require('util');

console.log('you sent: ' + util.inspect(req.body, { showHidden: false, depth: null }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the issue.  Vishnu was correct about using the urlencoded method of bodyParser - but the real issue was due to the .htaccess file.  I had to add the following for the POST requests to get through:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
```

Without explicitly allowing the header methods, the GoDaddy shared hosting was blocking them.